# Live graphs using python on website

Tags: python, html, graph

I have a website which has been built using HTML and PHP.

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have connected to this database and created several charts using Python.

I want to be able to publish these graphs on my website and make the graphs live (so that they are refreshed every 5 minutes or so with latest data). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a process to crontab to run the Python program every 5 minutes (assuming Linux). You could, alternatively, have the PHP call Python and await the refreshed file before responding with the page.

Comment: Is there any way to publish these graphs (live) to a URL and just embed that URL in the website, without having to constantly run the Python file?

Comment: @vignesh: If you are using Python to produce the graph, you have to run the Python program to produce a fresh graph. The image containing the graph is published on the web, but a new graph has to be produced to update it. You can run the Python program in response to an HTTP request by using Flask or Django. https://www.fullstackpython.com/django.html